# Qt - focus on a specified area of webpage

Tags: qt, webkit, scroll

I'm trying to create a plugin using QT that is able to open a webpage, yet I only want the window to be focused on a 300x300 pixel area. The area is somewhere in the middle of a page.

I was able to load the page and then perform a scrolling operation, but that doesn't seem very clean.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I checked the QtWebFrame class reference:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qwebframe.html
but maybe I'm missing something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need interaction with the page, you could call [`QWebFrame::render(QPainter* painter, const QRegion& clip)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#render-2) and draw it onto a widget, specifying `clip` to be the required area.